# invoice generation - thymeleaf, spring, itextpdf

Tags: java, spring, itext, thymeleaf

I have to create process which will output an invoice PDF file. We could not find better solution than creating an html file (with thymeleaf) and formatting it to PDF file with some kind of helper ( for example itextpdf ). But i encouraged some problems because i could not include css files and images. Is there any better solution ( free ) to deal with it? Or maybe u can help me with that? I will include my java code. Thank you!

```
@Service
public class InvoiceTemplateHelper {

private final TemplateEngine templateEngine;
private ServletContext ctx;
private HttpServletRequest request;

@Autowired
public InvoiceTemplateHelper(TemplateEngine templateEngine, ServletContext ctx, HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.templateEngine = templateEngine;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.request = request;
}

public String getHTMLInvoice() throws InvoiceCreationException {
    WebContext context = new WebContext(request, null, ctx);
    context.setVariable("invoiceTitle", "INVOICE/010101");

    String body = templateEngine.process("invoice", context);
    convertToPDF(body);
    return body;
}

public void convertToPDF(String body) throws InvoiceCreationException {
    try{
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("invoice.pdf"));
        document.open();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
        document.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
        //TODO MESSAGE FOR EXCEPTION
        throw new InvoiceCreationException();
    } catch ( DocumentException e){
        //TODO MESSAGE FOR EXCEPTION
        throw new InvoiceCreationException();
    }
}
}
```

And dummy html file with example styling and data.

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

a {
  color: #5D6975;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  width: 21cm;  
  height: 29.7cm; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  color: #001028;
  background: #FFFFFF; 
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
  font-size: 12px; 
  font-family: Arial;
}

header {
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#logo img {
  width: 90px;
}

h1 {
  border-top: 1px solid  #5D6975;
  border-bottom: 1px solid  #5D6975;
  color: #5D6975;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  background: url(../images/dimension.png);
}

#project {
  float: left;
}

#project span {
  color: #5D6975;
  text-align: right;
  width: 52px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

#company {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

#project div,
#company div {
  white-space: nowrap;        
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n-1) td {
  background: #F5F5F5;
}

table th,
table td {
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  color: #5D6975;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C1CED9;
  white-space: nowrap;        
  font-weight: normal;
}

table .service,
table .desc {
  text-align: left;
}

table td {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}

table td.service,
table td.desc {
  vertical-align: top;
}

table td.unit,
table td.qty,
table td.total {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

table td.grand {
  border-top: 1px solid #5D6975;;
}

#notices .notice {
  color: #5D6975;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

footer {
  color: #5D6975;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #C1CED9;
  padding: 8px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title th:remove="all">Taxi invoice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/style.css}" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
<header class="clearfix">
    <div id="logo">
        <img th:src="@{images/logo.png}"/>
    </div>
    <h1 th:text="${invoiceTitle}">Invoice</h1>
    <div id="company" class="clearfix">
        <div><p th:text="#{company.name}"></p></div>
        <div><p th:text="#{company.address}"></p></div>
        <div><p th:text="#{comapny.phoneNumber}"></p></div>
        <div>
            <a th:mail="'mailto:'+#{company.mail}">
                <p th:text="#{company.name}"></p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="project">
        <div><span>PROJECT</span> Website development</div>
        <div><span>CLIENT</span> John Doe</div>
        <div><span>ADDRESS</span> 796 Silver Harbour, TX 79273, US</div>
        <div><span>EMAIL</span> <a th:href="'mailto:'+#{company.mail}">john@example.com</a></div>
        <div><span>DATE</span> August 17, 2015</div>
        <div><span>DUE DATE</span> September 17, 2015</div>
    </div>
</header>
<main>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="service">SERVICE</th>
            <th class="desc">DESCRIPTION</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>QTY</th>
            <th>TOTAL</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="service">Design</td>
            <td class="desc">Creating a recognizable design solution based on the company's existing visual identity</td>
            <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
            <td class="qty">26</td>
            <td class="total">$1,040.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="service">Development</td>
            <td class="desc">Developing a Content Management System-based Website</td>
            <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
            <td class="qty">80</td>
            <td class="total">$3,200.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="service">SEO</td>
            <td class="desc">Optimize the site for search engines (SEO)</td>
            <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
            <td class="qty">20</td>
            <td class="total">$800.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="service">Training</td>
            <td class="desc">Initial training sessions for staff responsible for uploading web content</td>
            <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
            <td class="qty">4</td>
            <td class="total">$160.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">SUBTOTAL</td>
            <td class="total">$5,200.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">TAX 25%</td>
            <td class="total">$1,300.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="grand total">GRAND TOTAL</td>
            <td class="grand total">$6,500.00</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="notices">
        <div>NOTICE:</div>
        <div class="notice">A finance charge of 1.5% will be made on unpaid balances after 30 days.</div>
    </div>
</main>
<footer>
    Invoice was created on a computer and is valid without the signature and seal.
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use html and convert it to PDF with iText instead of building they PDF directly using iText methods?

Comment: First, html with thymeleaf is much easier to fill witch data and style. But if i will not be able to do that in reasonable time. I wil ltry to use plain itext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at pdfHtml. It's the latest iText add-on. It supports HTML5 and CSS 3.
There are some examples out already, so you should be able to get a quick start on converting your html into a pdf document.

Comment: can you provide the link please